# what is the maximum possible number of monsters you can defeat?

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

**Problem Statement:**

While playing an RPG game, you were assigned to complete one of the hardest quests in this game. There are `n` monsters you'll need to defeat in this quest. Each monster `i` is described with two integer numbers - `poweri` and `bonusi`. To defeat this monster, you'll need at least poweri experience points. If you try fighting this monster without having enough experience points, you lose immediately.

You will also gain `bonusi` experience points if you defeat this monster. You can defeat monsters in any order. The quest turned out to be very hard - you try to defeat the monsters but keep losing repeatedly. Your friend told you that this quest is impossible to complete. Knowing that, you're interested, what is the maximum possible number of monsters you can defeat?

**Input:**

The first line contains an integer, n, denoting the number of monsters.

The next line contains an integer, e, denoting your initial experience.

Each line i of the n subsequent lines (where 0 ≤ i < n) contains an integer, poweri, which
represents power of the corresponding monster.

Each line i of the n subsequent lines (where 0 ≤ i < n) contains an integer, bonusi, which represents bonus for defeating the corresponding monster.

**Sample cases:**

**Input**  2 123 78 130 10 0

**Output** 2

**Output description**

Initial experience level is 123 points.
Defeat the first monster having power of 78 and bonus of 10. Experience level is now 123+10=133.
Defeat the second monster.

What I have tried:

```
public static  int defeat(int [] monster,int bonus[],int n,int exp){
        if(n==0)
            return 0;
        
        if(n==1 && monster[0]<=exp)return 1;
        if(n==1 && monster[0]>exp) return 0;

        if(monster[n-1]<=exp){
            return defeat(monster,bonus,n-1,bonus[n-1]+exp )+ defeat(monster,bonus,n-1,exp);
        }else{
            return defeat(monster,bonus,n-1,exp);

        }


    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = s.nextInt();
        int exp = s.nextInt();
        int monst[] = new int[n];
        int bonus[] = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            monst[i] = s.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            bonus[i] = s.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(defeat(monst,bonus,n,exp));
    }
```

I am not getting correct answers with this solution.
I thought of this problem as 0/1 knapsack problem( correct me If I am wrong). Also can you provide me DP solution of this problem.

Comment: What are the constraints on `n`?

Comment: Well it is not given in the question statement

Comment: Have you tried just sorting the monsters?

Comment: No, I thought of making a list of  pair of bonus and monster and then sorting that  list. But I have not tried it

Comment: Feels like a search problem, like backtracking.  Need to search all possible combinations to make sure you've got the deepest possible tree.

Comment: I think when exp greater or equal, should check for both n-1 and n+1 indexes and you need to maintain an array to denote that monster(at index i) has been killed

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just sort the monsters from lowest to highest power required and defeat them in that order.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = s.nextInt();
    int exp = s.nextInt();
    int monst[] = new int[n];
    int bonus[] = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        monst[i] = s.nextInt();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        bonus[i] = s.nextInt();
    }
    class Monster {
        private final int power, bonus;
        public Monster(int power, int bonus){
            this.power = power;
            this.bonus = bonus;
        }
    }
    Monster[] monsters = new Monster[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) monsters[i] = new Monster(monst[i], bonus[i]);
    Arrays.sort(monsters, Comparator.comparingInt(m -> m.power));
    int count = 0;
    for(Monster m: monsters){
        if(exp < m.power) break;
        exp += m.bonus;
        ++count;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I am too simplistic, but I would try it as below:

First create a class `Monster` like this:

```
public class Monster
{
  final int m_Power;
  final int m_Bonus;

  public Monster( final int power, final int bonus )
  {
    m_Power = power;
    m_Bonus = bonus;
  }

  public final int getPower() { return m_Power; }
  public final int getBonus() { return m_Bonus; }
}
```

Next, initialise a list of Monsters like this:

```
public static void main( String... args ) 
{ 
  final var scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
  final var n = scanner.nextInt();
  final var experience = scanner.nextInt();
  final var power [] = new int [n];
  for( var i = 0; i < n; ++i ) 
  {
    power [i] = scanner.nextInt();
  }
  List<Monster> monsters = new ArrayList<>( n );
  for( var i = 0; i < n; ++i ) 
  {
    monsters.add( new Monster( power [i], scanner.nextInt();
  }
  monsters.sort( (m1,m2) ->
  { 
    final var p = m1.getPower() - m2.getPower();
    return p == 0 ? m2.getBonus() - m1.getBonus(() : p; 
  } ); //*1
  System.out.println( defeat( monsters, experience ) );
}
```

*1 -> this implementation of the comparator works well only for power and bonus values that are small compared to MAX_INT.

The list `monsters` now contains the monsters sorted by their power in ascending order; monsters with the same power are ordered by their bonus values in descending order.

Now my implementation of `defeat()` would look like this:

```
public final int defeat( final List<Monster> m, final int initialExperience )
{
  var experience = initialExperience;
  var retValue = 0;
  final Stack<Monster> monsters = new LinkedList<>( m );
  while( !monsters.empty() )
  {
    var monster = monsters.pop();
    if( experience > monster.getPower() )
    {
      experience += monster.getBonus();
      ++retValue;
    }
    else break;
  }
  return retValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            n=int(input())
            e=int(input())
            P=[]
            for i in range(n):
                P.append(int(input()))
            B=[]
            for i in range(n):
                B.append(int(input()))
            c=0
            f=True
            while n>0 and f:
                f=False
                i=0
                while i<n:
                    if e>=P[i]:
                        e+=B[i]
                        P.pop(i)
                        B.pop(i)
                        n-=1 
                        c+=1
                        f=True
                        i-=1
                    i+=1
            print(c)
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain your code, to show why it fix the issue and answer to the original question ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Player {
    int exp;

    public int getExp() {
        return exp;
    }

    public void setExp(int exp) {
        this.exp = exp;
    }
}

class Monster {
    int power;
    int bonus;

    public int getPower() {
        return this.power;
    }

    public int getBonus() {
        return this.bonus;
    }

    public void setBonus(int bonus) {
        this.bonus = bonus;
    }

    public void setPower(int power) {
        this.power = power;
    }
}

class Calc {
    public int calc() {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //number of monsters
        System.out.println("enter the number of monsters");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[n];
        System.out.println("enter the power of the player");
        Player player = new Player();
        player.setExp(sc.nextInt());
        //declaration of array type object of monster
        Monster monster[] = new Monster[n];
        //value setting completed
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            //allocation of object to the real
            monster[i] = new Monster();
            System.out.println("enter the power of monster");
            monster[i].setPower(sc.nextInt());
            System.out.println("enter the bonus that to be earned after killing the monster");
            monster[i].setBonus(sc.nextInt());
        }
        //calculate win or loose
        int count = 0;
        int flag = 0;
        //**
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (player.getExp() >= monster[i].getPower()) {
                player.setExp(player.getExp() + monster[i].getBonus());
                count = count + 1;
                // flag = flag + 1;
            } else if (player.getExp() < monster[i].getPower()) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    arr[j] = i;
                //count = count;
                flag = flag + 1;
            }
            //**
            for (int t = 0; t < flag; t++) {
                if (player.getExp() >= monster[arr[t]].getPower()) {
                    count = count + 1;
                }

            }
        }
        return count;
    }

}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        System.out.println("welcome to the loosing game");
        Calc c = new Calc();
        System.out.println("no of monster killed" + c.calc());
    }
}
```

Comment: this is my solution though this is not giving perfect result i would like if any one helps with the review part j turns to recheck the array to find monsters that could be killed after added bonus power

Comment: It's not at us to check if your code works. Personally, I'm here to check if you answer is good, and it seems to be unclear. So can you [edit] it to explain your code, to show why it fix the issue and answer to the original question ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct Monsters
{
   int power;
   int bonus;
};

class Solution
{
 public:
//Function to find the maximum number of activities that can
//be performed by a single person.
static bool compare(Monsters a, Monsters b)
{
    if(a.power < b.power) return 1;
    else if(a.power > b.power) return 0;
    else return 1;
}
int MonstersKill(vector<int> power, vector<int> bonus, int n, int exp)
{
    Monsters arr[n];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i].power = power[i];
        arr[i].bonus = bonus[i];
    }
    
    sort(arr, arr+n, compare);
    
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i].power <= exp)
        {
            count++;
            exp += arr[i].bonus;
        }
        else
          break;
    }
    
    return count;   
   }
};

 int main()
 {
    int n, exp;
    cin >> n >> exp;
    vector<int> power(n), bonus(n);
    
    //adding elements to arrays power and bonus
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>power[i];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>bonus[i];
    
    Solution ob;
    cout << ob.MonstersKill(power, bonus, n, exp) << endl;

  return 0;
 }
```

**Time Complexity : O(N * Log(N))**

**Auxilliary Space: O(N)**